# Output the array so that 10 elements per line are printed

Tags: java, arrays, loops, variables, element

I'm very new to java (like a month old). This week we have a programming problem that I'm having difficulty with. We are asked to write a program that declares an array "alpha" of 50 elements of type "double". Initialize the array so that the first 25 elements are equal to the square of the index variable and the last 25 elements are equal to three times the index variable. Output the array so that **10 elements per line are printed**. I've gotten the output right so far, but it's **still only printing 1 value per line**, here's what I have so far, what am I doing wrong? Any help is super appreciated!!

```
import java.util.*;
public class progprblm5{
public static void main(String[] args){

  double alpha[] = new double[50];

  for(int i =0;i<25;i++)
     {alpha[i]= i*i;}

  for(int i = 25;i<50;i++)
     {alpha[i]= i*i*i;}

  System.out.println( "The values are: ");
     for(int i=0;i<50;i++)   
  System.out.println(alpha[i]);
  }
  void print(double array[])
     {
     for(int i=1; i <= array.length; i++)
     {
  System.out.print(array[i+1]+ " , ");
     if(i%10==0)
  System.out.print("\n");
  }
  }
 }
```

Comment: You're not calling your `print()` method.

Comment: Good thing too, because it'll crash. You already know that indexes are 0-based. So iterating from 1, then doing `array[i+1]`, means you're treating it as 2-based, of all things. Maybe you meant `array[i-1]`?

Comment: Also, `i * i * i` is not *"three times the index variable"*. That the cube of the index variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have not called **print method** from main method. One more mistake is in your code that, you mentioned about **3 times of index variable** and in your code you are taking **cube of index variable**.

```
public class progprblm5{
     public static void main(String []args){
         double alpha[] = new double[50];
         for(int i =0;i<25;i++){
             alpha[i]= i*i;
         }
         for(int i = 25;i<50;i++){
             alpha[i]= 3*i;  // 3 times of index
         }
         System.out.println( "The values are: ");

         new progprblm5().print(alpha);  // method call
}
  void print(double array[]){
      for(int i=0; i < array.length; i++){ //iterate array from 0 index
            System.out.print(array[i]+ " , "); // print ith element
            if(i%10==0){
              System.out.println();
            }
      }
 }    
}
```